# HTML making a height 100% and auto

Tags: html, css, height

I have a `<div>` with the id middle and I have its height set to 
100% using `height:100%` the problem is that the items in the div are larger than the height. I  tried `height:calc( 100% + 120px );;` but since I use the same div id for all the pages some of much bigger than I would like if I use `height:calc( 100% + 120px );;`, and if I use `height:auto` some are much smaller than I would like them to be.

Instead I was looking for if there was a way to do something like `height:calc( 100% + auto );;` to make the height 100% of the screen and if the items exceeded the height for it to add the height it needed. Of course `height:calc( 100% + auto );;` did not work and searched around for a way to accomplish this but found thing that really worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-height: 100%`.

That will ensure 100% height, but not force an upper bound.